# Hitting set approximation

Tags: algorithms, approximation

I'm having a small problem understanding what is the result of the 4-approximation polynomial-time algorithm for 4-Hitting Set.

What I mean is that by solving 4-Hitting set I get a group X such that all subsets in the universe have a common element with X.

What can I say that the result of the approximation algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, the problem here is a minimization problem ("can I find a small bunch of guys from the universe of elements so that it hits all the sets of the input"?) so a 4-approximation will guarantee that the solution set, say $H$, that you find is  is at most 4 times larger than the optimal solution. So if the optimal solution was of size 10, then $H$ has size at most 40.

To summarize (based on your comments), if there is no valid solution, the approximation algorithm can't output a valid solution (of any size) either. Otherwise, if there is a solution, the approximation algorithm will output a solution that is *at most* four times the optimal. Note that it is perfectly possible that the solution outputted is optimal, twice the optimal, thrice the optimal, or whatever. The guarantee is that it is *at most* four times the optimal.

Comment: Well, what does your problem definition say? Is it a valid solution or not? Usually, k-hitting set means that the input sets have size at most k.

Comment: OK. The terminology I was referring to is also used in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-approximation_of_k-hitting_set). So you are surely looking for a solution of size at most q, but you can also restrict the sets to have size at most (or exactly) p.